# Why doesn't elasticsearch allow changes to an indexed data?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I tried to convert some of the fields in a previously indexed data from string to integer. But when i ran logstash again, the fields didn't get converted (checked in Kibana only). Why can't i make changes to an already indexed data and if not, how can i make the required changes to my index?

I've only been making changes in logstash. Here is a piece of logstash.conf:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "movie"
    path => "C:/TestLogs/Test5.txt"  
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
            match => {"message" => "(?<Movie_Name>[\w.\-\']*)\s(?<Rating>[\d.]+)\s(?<No. Of Downloads>\d+)\s(?<No. of views>\d+)" }
        }
    mutate {
        convert => {"Rating" => "float"}
        convert => {"No. of Downloads" => "integer"}
        convert => {"No. of views" => "integer"}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch is using Lucene at its core for indexing and storing data. Lucene uses a read-only datastructure to store data and that's the reason why it is not possible to change data structures for data that is already stored in elasticsearch. It is possible to update the documents with new values, but not to change the structure for an entire index.

If you want to change the mappings, i.e. the data structure then you have to create a new index with a new mapping and store it there.

This of course is not that easy if elasticsearch is the master of the data. To do this you have to create a new index with a new mapping and read data from the old index and put it into the new index. You can do this by using the [Scan and Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) approach.

If you want to make this transparent to the application reading from elasticsearch you can use an alias:

At first the index name is `data_v1` and the alias is `data`:

```
data -> data_v1
```

Then you create a new index: `data_v2` with the new mapping. Read all data from `data_v1` and store it in `data_v2`. Having done this, change the alias to point to `data_v2`

```
data -> data_v2
```

To change aliases you can use the 'remove' and 'add' functions:

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions": [
        { "remove": {
            "alias": "items",
            "index": "items_v1"
        }}
    ]
}

POST /_aliases
{
    "actions": [
        { "add": {
            "alias": "items",
            "index": "items_v2"
        }}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could make it more clear that it's totally fine to update documents but that the _mappings_ can't be changed without reindexing.

Comment: @paweloque : So if i make the changes in logstash.conf, i can do the mapping through elasticsearch and finally the changes will be reflected in kibana?

Comment: @kaks how does your logstash.conf look like? If you change it there, you probably have to delete the index, set a new mapping and then reindex data.

Comment: @paweloque : Please check my edited question. I've included a part of my logstash.conf file.

Comment: i added an alias to point to my existing index. 
`PUT /movie1_indexer/_alias/mov1` 
How do i make the alias `mov1` to point to a new index using sense plugin so that i can delete my old index?

Comment: @paweloque : when i create a new index and point the alias to the new index, no documents are pushed into the new index. I want to push the updated documents from the old index to the new one to make the updates.When i use the scan and scroll approach with scroll id , it shows a parsing error "unit is missing or unrecognized".

Comment: I've opened a new topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332385/not-able-to-reindex-data-in-elasticsearch